# How to find 10 most common words in a text

Tags: c#, text

So I have *arbitrary text* in a txt file and I need to find the *10 most common words*. How should I do that? I think I should read sentences from dot to a dot and put it to an array, but don't really know how to do that.

Comment: What have u tried so far?

Comment: Split text to words, group by these words, order by count (in descending order), take top 10

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could achieve it with Linq. Try something like this:

```
var words = "two one three one three one";
var orderedWords = words
  .Split(' ')
  .GroupBy(x => x)
  .Select(x => new { 
    KeyField = x.Key, 
    Count = x.Count() })
  .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
  .Take(10);
```

Comment: `ToList()` is *redundant*: `...words.Split(' ').GroupBy(x => x)...`

Comment: Very true Dmitry, it is not needed. I edited the code sample.

Comment: If you are given a "*random text* in a txt file" your current routine'll experience difficulties: you have to remove all the *punctuations* (*commas*, *full stops*, etc.); you have to deal with *case*, e.g. `"One is just one, but not ONE inc."` - the word `one` appears *twice*

Comment: Counter example: `var words = "Two to one,  three to one and three . One. One and three";` The most common word should be `"One"` but `"three"` is returned.

Answer (score 3):

convert all the data to String, and split it into array

example :

```
char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', ',', '.', ':', '\t' };
string text = "one\ttwo three:four,five six seven";

string[] words = text.Split(delimiterChars);

var dict = new Dictionary<String, int>();
foreach(var value in array)
{
    if (dict.ContainsKey(value))
        dict[value]++;
    else
        dict[value] = 1;
}

for(int i=0;i<dict.length();i++) //or i<10
{
   Console.WriteLine(dict[i]);
}
```

you need to sort the array with bigger value first.

Comment: Counter example: `text = "One, Two, Three, Four, four, five";` the expected result is the `"Four"` being on the top. The actual outcome is the *empty string* rules them all.

Answer (score 1):

The most difficult part of the task is to *split* the initial text to words. *Natural language* (e.g. English) word is quite a complex thing:

```
Forget-me-not     // 1 word (a nice blue flower) 
Do not Forget me! // 4 words
Cannot            // 1 word or shall we split "cannot" into "can" + "not"?
May not           // 2 words
George W. Bush    // Is "W" a word?
W.A.S.P.          // ...If it is, is it equal to "W" in the "W.A.S.P"?
Donald Trump      // Homonyms: name
Spades is a trump // ...and a special follow in a game of cards 
It's an IT; it is // "It" and "IT" are different (IT is an acronym), "It" and "it" are same
```

Another issue is the case: you may want to count `It` and `it` as one and the *same word*, but `IT` as a different *acronym*. As a first try, I suggest something like this:

```
var top10words = File
  .ReadLines(@"C:\MyFile.txt")
  .SelectMany(line => Regex
    .Matches(value, @"[A-Za-z-']+")
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select(match => CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(match.Value)))
  .GroupBy(word => word)
  .Select(chunk => new {
     word = chunk.Key,
     count = chunk.Count()})
  .OrderByDescending(item => item.count)
  .ThenBy(item => item.word)
  .Take(10);
```

In my solution I've assumed:

- Words can contain `A..Z, a..z`, `-` (dash) and `'` (apostroph) letters only
- `TitleCase` has been used to separate all upper case acronyms from regular words (`It` and `it` will be treat as the same word, while `IT` as different one)
- In case of *tie* (two or many words have the same frequence) this tie is breaking by alphabet order

Answer (score 1):

Here is a combined method I wrote from the answers provided by [Aldi Renaldi Gunawan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4627409/aldi-renaldi-gunawan) and [JanneP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7049942/jannep). I guess the delimiter chars will depend on your use case though. In your case you can provide `10` for the `numWords` parameter.

```
public static Dictionary<string, int> WordCount(string text, int numWords = int.MaxValue)
{
    var delimiterChars = new char[] { ' ', ',', ':', '\t', '\"', '\r', '{', '}', '[', ']', '=', '/' };
    return text
        .Split(delimiterChars)
        .Where(x => x.Length > 0)
        .Select(x => x.ToLower())
        .GroupBy(x => x)
        .Select(x => new { Word = x.Key, Count = x.Count() })
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
        .Take(numWords)
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Word, x => x.Count);
}
```